# For regression, how many kinds of loss function are there? And what are they and when we should use them?

Tags: regression, tensorflow, loss

I just find the good **loss function** for **regression problem**. Then use it in ***Tensorflow***.

In the API of tensorflow, there are a lot of loss function, most of them are designed for classification problem.

For regression problem, *any other good loss function except the **MSE***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following list of fitting targets in my code:

lowest sum of squared absolute error

lowest sum of squared relative error

lowest sum of squared orthogonal distance

lowest sum of absolute value of absolute error

lowest sum of squared log[abs(predicted/actual)]

lowest sum of absolute value of relative error

lowest peak absolute value of absolute error

lowest peak absolute value of relative error

lowest Akaike Information Criterion

lowest Bayesian Information Criterion

Usually the standard lowest sum of squared absolute error is sufficient for my needs, though I have occasionally used the lowest sum of squared relative error. I have only used the other fitting targets rarely or as needed to reduce the fitting effect of outliers in the data.

Comment: thanks for your answer， can you explain or add some links to make me have better understanding to these loos function?

Comment: These are the statistics to be minimized by the fitting software. For example, "lowest sum of squared relative error" means that the fitting code will minimuze the sum of the squared relative errors. When using a non-linear solver such as gradient descent the software would try to find the minimum value of the sum of squared relative errors. I do not have individual links for each fitting target, each is a goal for the fitting software to find parameters for.

Comment: Got it. Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 0):

See the more concise and readily available listing of sub-linear loss functions as discussed in the scipy documentation for robust non-linear regression.

The soft_l1 is often effective at capturing the underlying significance while rejecting outliers. Especially important if you have outliers with high leverage in a sparse data set.

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html